# How to make the whole datagrid take up same color including the empty data cells

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to give the same gray color to the empty datagrid cells just like the ones filled with data. Tried by setting the background of DataGridCell as well as Datagrid to Gray but still this white color comes for empty cells.

[image]

Comment: Are they transparent? Have you tried setting the background colour of the form?

Comment: I actually just need to set color for datagrid. Rest entire background is blue. How can we find out these empty cells in datagrid ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the whole grid row via the `RowStyle`. Here is an example

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:People x:Key="People">
        <model:Person First="Joe" Last="Smith" Phone="303-555-5555" />
        <model:Person First="Jenny" Last="Johnson" Phone="720-867-5309" />
        <model:Person First="Frank" Last="Wright" Phone="202-555-5555" />
    </model:People>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridDemoRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource People}"
            AlternationCount="3"
            RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridDemoRowStyle}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding First}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Name" Binding="{Binding Last}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Binding="{Binding Phone}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Result**

[image]